# Google Extensions - Running in background

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a google extension that plays music. I want the extension to also play when I close the extension and surf other sites. Do I have to change the code of the manifest.json, background.html, or main.html (my index/popup file)? Here is the code of my manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "SpeedSongz.fm",
    "description": "Instantly listen to your favorite music and radios.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_title": "SpeedSongz.fm",
        "popup": "main.html"
    },
    "background_page" : "background.html"
}
```

So how do I make the code so that the music will keep running in the background even thought the actual extension is closed? Is it possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> plus feature could be, to create two function in bakcround page, one
>   stops the music, and the other restarts it:
>
> ```
> function stop(){
>
> }
>
> function start(){
>
> }
> ```
>
> So, when the user opens main.html, there could be two icons with two
>   listeners on it, each one could call background pages function, like:
>
> ```
> var backgroundpage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
> $("start_button").click(function(){
> backgroundpage.start();
> });
>
> $("stop_button").click(function(){
> backgroundpage.stop();
> });
> ```
>
> :)

Edit:

**popup.html:**

```
<html><head><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var bgp = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    $("#start_btn").click(function(){
        bgp.start();
    });

    $("#stop_btn").click(function(){
        bgp.stop();
    });
});
</script>
</head><body>
<div>
    <button type="button" id="start_btn">Start</button>
    <button type="button" id="stop_btn">Stop</button>
</div>
</body></html>
```

**background.html:**

```
<html><head><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script>
var audio = new Audio('guitar.mp3');
audio.loop="loop";
audio.play();

function start(){
    audio.play();
}

function stop(){
    audio.pause();
}

</script>
</head><body></body></html>
```

And thats it :)

Comment: Can I play it via html5 audio tag? This doesn't work: <audio autoplay="autoplay"><source src="test.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio> but in popup does (audio stops when I close this popup).

Comment: I edited my answer, in manifest, you only need to register a popup, and the background page. regards

Answer (score 2):

[Background pages](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html) serve exactly this purpose.  They act like regular pages, but are invisible (unless you access developer mode of course).  A background page is active the entire time that your extension is loaded.

In order to communicate with the background page from your site you would use a content script and send a message to the page.

Comment: Here is the reference for [message pqssing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html).  Your background page should contain an audio element and should play/pause it when gets certain messages.